# How can I terminate many spawned processes without going to each window and do CTRL + C?

Tags: batch-file

My full question is: How can I terminate the spawned processes without going to each individual window and do <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> them manually after I am done with them, whenever I decide it is so?

Currently my batch file looks like this:

```bat
pushd "System"
start call "#1"
popd
pushd "System(#02)"
start call "#2"
popd
pushd "System(#03KFLM)"
start call "#3"
popd
pushd "System(#04Toy)"
start call "#4"
popd
pushd "System(#05Toy)"
start call "#5"
popd
pushd "System(#06Toy)"
start call "#6"
popd
pushd "System(#07TFF)"
start call "#7"
popd
pushd "System(#08TFF)"
start call "#8"
popd
pushd "System(#09TFF)"
start call "#9"
popd
pushd "System(#10TFF)"
start call "#10"
popd
pushd "System(#11TFF)"
start call "#11"
popd
pushd "System(#12TFF)"
start call "#12"
popd
pushd "System(#13TFF)"
start call "#13"
popd
pushd "System(#14TFF)"
start call "#14"
popd
pushd "System(#15TFF)"
start call "#15"
popd
pushd "System(#16TFF)"
start call "#16"
popd
pushd "System(#17TFF)"
start call "#17"
popd
pushd "System(#18TFF)"
start call "#18"
popd
pushd "System(#19NFF)"
start call "#19"
popd
pushd "System(#20PLA)"
start call "#20"
popd
pushd "System(#21Testing)"
start call "#21"
popd
pushd "System(#22TMSL)"
start call "#22"
popd
pushd "System(#23TMHL)"
start call "#23"
popd
pushd "System(#24TMXL)"
start call "#24"
popd
pushd "System(#25Portal)"
start call "#25"
popd
pushd "System(#26DSKF)"
start call "#26"
popd
pushd "System(#27AKF)"
start call "#27"
popd
pushd "System(#28PAKF)"
start call "#28"
popd
pushd "System(#29VM)"
start call "#29"
popd
pushd "System(#30DM)"
start call "#30"
popd
pushd "System(#31PureDoom3KF)"
start call "#31"
popd
pushd "System(#32Halloween2011)"
start call "#32"
popd
pushd "System(#33Halloween2011)"
start call "#33"
popd
pushd "System(#34Perthians)"
start call "#34"
popd
pushd "System(#35Perthians)"
start call "#35"
popd
pushd "System(#36Perthians)"
start call "#36"
popd
pushd "System(#37Perthians)"
start call "#37"
popd
pushd "System(#38Perthians)"
start call "#38"
popd
pushd "System(#39Deep)"
start call "#39"
popd
pushd "SumoCtryTagsServer"
start call "start-server"
popd
ServerPage
```

This is to start up some game servers, the # prefix and number after it, is real and not a substitute and is relating to a batch file inside those relative folders. The ServerPage is a python file so ends in .py extension if it matters but the rest are batch files as mentioned above ending in a .bat extension.

This works fine when I want to boot up 40 servers + 1 script at once but what about if I want to quit those started 41 processes once I'm done with them?

I would go onto each processes' window and press <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> 41 times since there is 41 of them, maybe 82, or more times if they decide to throw you a visual C++ error or something which requires pressing it twice or more for it to respond back...

Sure, pressing the X at the top right corner is faster than simply <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, but will result in an abrupt termination and so any log files that are currently in progress will not correctly close or save. With <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, this gives the server enough time to properly save and close any logs they may have opened and safely shutdown. So that why I must use <kbd>CRTL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> method....

Comment: The code you provided is definitely not what I call a [mcve]...

Comment: @double-beep Sorry, been busy with other stuff, sorry it doesn't work, some servers error out with "Windows cannot find '#n'. Make sure you typed the name correctly, and then try again." where n is one of the batch files that's supposedly called.

Comment: @double-beep The taskkill command at the end also doesn't work either.....it processes them alright as I can see the echo log, but none of the 39/40 windows closes......so I have to cross them out manually....or maybe I need to just let them fully load and then press a key for the next step of the batch launcher to task kill them all......

Comment: Ok so I let all the servers get loaded fully and then pressed a key so the batch should process the next lot, and lo and be hold, nothing happens, after a echo screen or what appears to be showing that it works or if it does work then well for some reason it doesn't work on the spawned servers.....also that doesn't start the ServerPage python file.....so not sure where I would add that in into the lot....if you want, I can whip out my phone and take a video of the process showing you what's going on from outside, because I would run out of memory if I used a screen recorder....heh....

Answer (score 0):

The way to do that, is to use `taskkill`, a command used to terminate(/kill) processes with a combination of a `for /L` loop which is used to loop through numbers.

Use the following code:

```bat
for /L %%A IN (1 1 41) do (
    for /F "delims=" %%B IN ('dir /B /AD "System(#*%%A*)"') do (
        pushd "%%B" && (
            start "%%A" "#%%A"
            popd
        ) || (
            echo cannot find folder %%B. Please be sure you are in the correct directory.
        )
    )
)

pause

for /L %%C IN (1 1 41) do taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %%C" /F
```

If you have an image name, do `taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq %%C" /F /IM imagename.exe`.

Note that:

- Starting 41 separate processes with 122 lines of code is quite useless. Loop through 1-41 and start the processes.
- Not sure what you need `start call`. Is there something special you want to achieve? I have removed that, since it is used in rare situations.
- `start "num" "#num"`: `num` is the window title; `#num` is the process to start.

For more info about the commands used, type in `cmd.exe`:

- **`for /?`** also explains the `for /L`
- `pushd /?`
- `start /?`
- `call /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `popd /?`
- **`taskkill /?`** explanation of the usage

Comment: I would certainly adjust the methodology to this: `PushD "%%A" 2>Nul && (Start "%%A" "#%%A" 2>Nul & PopD)`. This ensures that the `Start` and `PopD` commands are invoked only if the `PushD` command was successful. Currently your code would invoke the `PopD` command regardless of whether there is a matching `PushD` and could obviously try to `Start` a process, even though there wasn't a relevant directory to invoke it from. _It is likely that the directories do already exist, but for the sake of a pair of parentheses and a couple of StdErr redirections, it is a sensible extra few bytes to add._

Comment: Please check post, I have added and clarified my post a bit more....if that matters...

Comment: > `Not sure what you need start call. Is there something special you want to achieve? I have removed that, since it is used in rare situations.`

Like what kind of rare situations? I only used it coz I saw someone else use it and it looked cleaner than my previous batch code......and it works too to boot! So what's wrong with using it?

Edit: *sigh* paragraphing is disabled in comments...